# Hidden info being passed in a form submission securely in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to submit extra information in to the db when a form is submitted like a genre name. One way is hidden fields on the form. But they can be messed with and aren't very secure, i don't want the possibility of a user changing the information being added to the db other than the info they entered in the visible form inputs.

How can I pass something like 'romance' to the genre_name column on a from submission without the user changing it?

Comment: Is there a reason the genre needs to be in the form? How is it determined?

Comment: How about implementing a logic in the controller to decide which genre_name needs to be set depending on a different factor set? Seems about the best way to do it without risking having users temper with the data.

Another thing to think about, leave it in the form and validate its value after submission to ensure that it's valid.

Comment: @MikeGorski once the user submits the form it then needs to be approved by a mod. Once it is approved it is sent to the right db table depending on its genre. The genre is grabbed from params, but i'm not sure how to save it in the db without the user being able to change it.

Comment: @user3234020 then I'd go with what Alexandre Voyer said, set the genre_name in the controller.